# z-index and position properties spacing

Tags: css

I am sure this is a very confusing matter for most new developers.
And i am sorry if this subject was asked before, but i cant find a solution for a long time.

I am trying to create a video cover background, place some divs above it and then keep making divs under it.

Things become a little complicated when i started to work beneath the video cover.
 - they appear beneath which is okay, but styling them with for example margins or placing 
 tags affect immidiately the video cover div above which is confusing.

this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-video" style="background: #0e284d url('https://cont-edu.technion.ac.il/wp-content/themes/cont-edu/assets/images/intro-video-poster.jpg?v=1.1.65') 50% bottom no-repeat;">
      <video preload="none" poster="https://cont-edu.technion.ac.il/wp-content/themes/cont-edu/assets/images/empty.gif" autoplay loop>
      <source src="https://cont-edu.technion.ac.il/wp-content/themes/cont-edu/assets/images/intro.mp4?v=1.1.65" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-bg js-parallax" style="background: #0e284d url('https://cont-edu.technion.ac.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/intro-home.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: 100;">
    <p>
      some text here
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

[preview pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgxRbZ)

I am willing to place a video cover at the top of the sit. then add some content above the video. and then keep adding content under the video without affecting the positions and styles of the video and its above content.

any help would be aprriciated. thanks!

EDIT: By under the video i mean down the webpage..not actually under the video.

Comment: take a look at this: http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/mRjvPa. Try using z-index from 0 to high since in the mind of the browser negative values wont matter/stack according to logic.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i actually tried that. But in your example aswell, no content under the video..  when i meant under i meant down the page, not actually under the video. sorry

Comment: Can you check that again? http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/mRjvPa

Comment: Didnt actually understood what you did.. my issue is that i want a cover background with live video, with some content over it. and then keep working down the page with more content without both parts intercepting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the professional way to make it work.
I had to create another div under the video. and it also had to be with some content in it.

I have added a div with visibility set to hidden.

Then i could keep working on rest of the page.

I would appriciate any further comments about the topic and improvements.

thank you!